# How to upload encrypted image file on google drive from android using Google Drive API

Tags: android, encryption, google-drive-api

I want to upload the encrypted image file from Android to a user-specific google drive, Also want to Decrypt the image while loading in-app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following function It will upload encrypted image file on google drive and also downloading the decryption image save it to the app private files folder.

```
suspend fun uploadFileToGDrive(path: String?, suffix: String?): String {
    getDriveService()?.let { googleDriveService ->
        try {
            if (path != null) {
                Log.e("pathGD", path)
            }

            googleDriveService.fetchOrCreateAppFolder(
                context.getString(R.string.application_folder),
                preferenceHelper
            )
            val encryptedData = ImageCrypto().encryptFile("$path")
            Log.e("encryptedData", encryptedData)

            val actualFile = File(encryptedData)
            if (!actualFile.exists()) error("File $actualFile not exists.")
            val gFile = com.google.api.services.drive.model.File()
            // gFile.name = actualFile.name
            val formatter = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss")
            var dateString = formatter.format(Date())

            gFile.name = dateString + suffix
            gFile.parents = listOf(preferenceHelper.getFolderId())
          
            val fileContent = FileContent("image/jpeg", actualFile)
            val create = googleDriveService.files().create(gFile, fileContent)
                .setFields("id, parents")
                .execute()
            driveFilePathId = create.id

        } catch (exception: Exception) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
        }
    } ?: ""
   Toast.makeText(context, "Please Log In first!", LENGTH_LONG).show()
    return driveFilePathId
}
```

and I have uploaded encryption and decryption image using AES on my github profile. Please check.

https://github.com/meshramaravind/FileEncryptedAES

And when you display image from google drive. you need to download the image using decryption.

First download the image from google drive function call.

```
 fun downloadFileFromGDrive(id: String) {
    getDriveService()?.let { googleDriveService ->
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            Log.e("idDownload", id)
            val file = File(context.filesDir, "${id}.jpg")
            if(!file.exists()) {
                try {
                    val gDriveFile = googleDriveService.Files().get(id).execute()
                    createDirectoryAndSaveImagePackage(gDriveFile.id)
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    println("!!! Handle Exception $e")
                }
            }
        }
    } ?: ""
    //Toast.makeText(context, "Please Log In first!", LENGTH_SHORT).show()
}
```

and save it to the app private files folder:

```
 fun createDirectoryAndSaveImagePackage(id: String?) {
    getDriveService()?.let { googleDriveService ->
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val file = File(context.filesDir, "${id}.jpg")
            Log.e("fileEncryptedDirGD", "$file")
            try {
                val outputStream = FileOutputStream(file)
                googleDriveService.files()[id]
                    .executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream)
                if (id != null) {
                    googleDriveService.readFile(id)
                }
                val decryptedDataDir = ImageCrypto().decryptFile("$file")
                Log.e("decryptedDataDir", decryptedDataDir)
                outputStream.flush()
                outputStream.close()

            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
}


  and display image jetpack compose.
```

fun displayImage() {

val fileGD = File(context.filesDir, "${it1}.jpg")
if (fileGD.exists()) {
val decryptedData2 =
ImageCrypto().decryptFile("$fileGD")

```
                                       val painterBitmap = rememberImagePainter(
                                        data = File(decryptedData2),
                                        builder = {
                                            crossfade(500)
                                        })

                                    val painterState = painterBitmap.state

                                    val painter =
                                        rememberImagePainter(
                                            data = File(decryptedData2),
                                            builder = {
                                                placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
                                                error(R.drawable.placeholder)
                                            })


                                    if (painterState is ImagePainter.State.Loading) {
                                        CircularProgressIndicator(
                                            modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center),
                                            color = MaterialTheme.colors.secondary
                                        )

                                    } else {

                                        Image(
                                            painter = painter,
                                            contentScale = ContentScale.Inside,
                                            modifier = Modifier
                                                .width(200.dp)
                                                .height(100.dp)
                                                .padding(PADDING / 2),
                                            contentDescription = null,
                                        )
                                    }
                                   }
                                   }
```